# jquery ajax file upload, success doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm using jquery to upload images to a joomla site, but have problems with the file ajaxfileupload.js. The images upload just fine, but the function in "success" doesn't get called. And I need it to work to show a confirmation that the upload is finished. I have tried using "complete" instead of "success" and then the code works, but it refreshes the page over and over agian. How can I make it work like it should? Here's the code..

```
upload: function (a) {
    if (jQuery("#Filedata-" + a).val() == "") {
        jQuery("#photoupload-" + a).remove();
        joms.uploader.upload();
        if (jQuery("#photoupload").next().length == 0) {
            joms.uploader.addNewUpload()
        }
        jQuery("#upload-photos-button").show();
        return
    }
    var c = (jQuery("#photoupload-" + a + " :input:checked").val() == "1") ? "&defaultphoto=1" : "";
    var b = jQuery("#photoupload-" + a).next().find(".elementIndex").val();
    b = (b != "") ? "&nextupload=" + b : "";
    jQuery("#photoupload-" + a).children().each(function () {
        jQuery(this).css("display", "none")
    });
    jQuery("#photoupload-" + a).append('<div id="photoupload-loading-' + a + '"><span class="loading" style="display:block;float: none;margin: 0px;"></span><span>' + joms.uploader.uploadText + "</span></div>");
    jQuery.ajaxFileUpload({
        url: this.postUrl + c + b,
        secureuri: false,
        fileElementId: "Filedata-" + a,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (e, d) {
            jQuery("#photoupload-loading-" + a).remove();
            if (typeof (e.error) != "undefined" && e.error == "true") {
                jQuery("#photoupload-" + a).css("background", "#ffeded");
                jQuery("#photoupload-" + a).append('<span class="error">' + e.msg + "</span>")
            } else {
                jQuery("#photoupload-" + a).css("background", "#edfff3");
                jQuery("#photoupload-" + a).append('<span class="success">' + e.msg + "</span>")
            }
            jQuery("#photoupload-" + a).fadeOut(4500, function () {
                jQuery("#photoupload-" + a).remove();
                if (jQuery("#photoupload").next().length == 0) {
                    joms.uploader.addNewUpload()
                }
            });
            jQuery("#photoupload-" + a + " .remove").css("display", "block");
            if (e.nextupload != "undefined") {
                joms.uploader.upload(e.nextupload);
                return
            } else {
                jQuery("#upload-photos-button").show()
            }
        },
        error: function (f, d, g) {}
    });
    return false
}
```

Comment: What is the error. You can use the error:function to get the error.

Comment: Could you post the JSON sent by the server?

Comment: just alert the error message and check

Comment: the alert shows the following error message:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: JSON response is:
 {msg: 'Photo uploaded successfully.',nextupload: '2'}

Answer (score 5):

I think I solved the problem. You have to remove the options: data,datatype. It will work fine.

Comment: Worked for me too. I don't like it but I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be late though but for people seeing this for the first time just change
 dataType: "json",
to 
 dataType: "JSON",

Comment: Doing this opened up a whole new can of worms.